# Arquillian: Can not run tests from IDE

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss, jboss-arquillian

My test looks like

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TweetStreamTest {

    @ArquillianResource
    URI uri;

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addClasses(TweetStreamServer.class, TweetStreamClient.class);
    }

    @RunAsClient
    @Test
    public void test() throws URISyntaxException {
        System.out.println("URI: " + getEndpointUrl());
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    private URI getEndpointUrl() throws URISyntaxException {
        return new URI("ws://" + uri.getHost() +
                ":" + uri.getPort() + uri.getPath());
    }
}
```

My maven dependencies look like

```
<properties>
    <org.wildfly>8.0.0.Final</org.wildfly>
    <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<groupId>com.self</groupId>
<artifactId>tweetstream</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>clean install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add Arquillian -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add Container Adapter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>wildfly-managed-arquillian</id>
        <properties>
            <browser>chromium-browser</browser>
            <serverProfile>standalone-full.xml</serverProfile>
            <serverRoot>${project.build.directory}/wildfly-${org.wildfly}</serverRoot>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
                <artifactId>undertow-websockets-jsr</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Beta25</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-json-p-provider</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <version>${org.wildfly}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </testResource>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources-wildfly-managed</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack</id>
                            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>unpack</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                        <version>${org.wildfly}</version>
                                        <type>zip</type>
                                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <JBOSS_HOME>${project.build.directory}/wildfly-${org.wildfly}</JBOSS_HOME>
                        </environmentVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This runs fins on command line when I run it as  `mvn -Pwildfly-managed-arquillian`. When I run it through IDE (I use IntelliJ IDEA), I get error as

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not start container
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:208)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.start(CommonDeployableContainer.java:112)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:70)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachSuiteContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:221)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startSuiteContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:104)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:94)
    ... 65 more
```

**Question**
When do I need to do in order to run this test from IDEA?

I am pretty sure I am missing something very basic, but do not know why

Comment: Did you try to set "Working Directory" to MODULE_DIR?

Comment: Yes, I did and error is still the same

Answer (score 5):

Are you on Linux? I was having the same issue, but in my case it happened both in IDEA and in the terminal. The culprit was the lack of the JBOSS_HOME environment variable. Try setting it with

```
export JBOSS_HOME=/path/to/wildfly-X.X.X/
```

and then running IDEA from the same terminal. If it works, put the `export` command in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Correct answer, at least for me :)

Answer (score 1):

In your arquillian.xml put:

```
<property name="jbossHome">/path/to/wildfly</property>
```

And this is the final file:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
   <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />
   <container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
        <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">/path/to/wildfly</property>
        </configuration>
   </container>
</arquillian>
```